# How many physical processors does ubuntu support?

Tags: cpu

How many physical processors does ubuntu support?  I have a 4 socket server mainboard with 4 dual core AMD Opterons.  Will Ubuntu support all 8 processors.  I also have plans to upgrade to 6 core Opterons making this a 24 processor machine.  Any problem supporting this many processors?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### 12.04 LTS (and later):

- Desktop/Server **32-bit**: 8 cores/CPUs
- Desktop/Server **64-bit**: 256 cores/CPUs (but LiveCD supports 64 by default)

#### 11.10 and below, including 10.04 LTS

- Desktop/Server 32-bit: 8 cores/CPUs
- Desktop 64-bit: 64 cores/CPUs
- Server 64-bit: 256 cores/CPUs

Comment: Could you also link to official sources?